# PrimeFlex not working on Angular Version 13

Tags: primeng, primeflex

I have installed primeFlex(Version 3.4.1) on my angular application(Version 13.1). I followed the instructions on their webpage https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/primeflex
but nothing works... in the developer console - isee that their class is empty..
i made all the instructions -

```
npm i primeflex
```

addind the css to the angular.json file

````
    "src/styles.scss",
    "./node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css"
],```

nothing work....
````

Answer (score 2):

I'm working with angular15, and I needed to add this rows to the styles.scss file and then it works for me:

```
@import 'node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css';
@import 'node_modules/primeflex/themes/saga-blue.css';
```

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE 1/3/2023 PrimeNg 15

the site and links was updated. now you have in the side bar links to both version  of PrimeFlex 2 and 3

### old answer for PrimeNg 13

in the PrimeNG site https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/primeflex
they forgot to update to version 3 docs... they are still in version 2 there that it is absolutely diffrent. if you install it from npm you got version 3 anf above automaticly...
so it confuse

just go to the official site of primeflex and read there how to use their ready made classes
https://www.primefaces.org/primeflex/

Answer (score 0):

first time after importing this in the style.css not solved my issue

@import 'node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css';
@import 'node_modules/primeflex/themes/saga-blue.css';

i was using primeflex 2.0.0 and i have checked on my node_modules their was no theme folder, so please cross check if it's not their upgrade primeflex to 3.0

i hope this will fix the issue, if it helped you like this